# unable to find a link from a table using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to search a link and click on it which is located in a table but the text by which I am trying to search the link is located in other  tag

the table is

`<table><tbody><tr><td>1.</td><td><a href="dynamic/somelocation/link">Link</a></td><td>Refrence text</td><td>Another text</td><td>another text</td><td>more data</td><td>data</td></tr></tbody></table>`

I tried so many things
but nothing worked for me

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="G:\\python\\driver\\chromedriver")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get("https:webpagelink.aspx")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

data=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
#i don't know how to handle after it
for ln in data
     if ln.text="Refrence text"
        ln.click()

      ```
````

Comment: How reference text and link your are  trying to access is related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
locator = '//td[contains(text(),"Reference text")]/..//a'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator).click()
```

Or if you want to use the exact match, try this

```
locator = '//td[text()="Reference text"]/..//a'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator).click()
```

Comment: there are several lines from which I need to open each matched link in a new window thanks for your help

Comment: OK. So, each link has different known text or what?

Comment: some times the refrence text partially matched

Comment: So, when you will be able to specify the situation and your question clearly it will be more possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

use `link_text` :

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Link')
```

or

```
find_element_by_xpath("a[@href='somelocation']")
```

Not sure why are you using `find_elements` : (But if that is all you want you can try with below code)

```
data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr")
for ln in data:
     if ln.text =="Refrence text":
        ln.click()
```

Comment: There are many rows in which  I am searching for one by refrence text